# Postgresql array unique aggregation

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a large table with structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  id SERIAL primary key ,
  a_list int[] not null,
  b_list int[] not null,
  c_list int[] not null,
  d_list int[] not null,
  type int not null 
)
```

I want query all unique values from `a_list`, `b_list`, `c_list`, `d_list` for `type` like this

```
    select 
        some_array_unique_agg_function(a_list), 
        some_array_unique_agg_function(b_list), 
        some_array_unique_agg_function(c_list), 
        some_array_unique_agg_function(d_list),
        count(1) 
    where type = 30
```

For example, for this data

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| id | a_list  | b_list | c_list | d_list  | type |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+------+  
| 1  | {1,3,4} | {2,4}  | {1,1}  | {2,4,5} | 30   |
| 1  | {1,2,4} | {2,4}  | {4,1}  | {2,4,5} | 30   |
| 1  | {1,3,5} | {2}    | {}     | {2,4,5} | 30   |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+------+
```

I want the next result

```
+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+-------+
| a_list      | b_list | c_list | d_list    | count |
+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+-------+  
| {1,2,3,4,5} | {2,4}  | {1,4}  | {2,4,5}   | 3     |
+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

Is there `some_array_unique_agg_function` for my purposes?

Comment: `uniq()` from the [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.27.6)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need some aggregate function like uniq to merge all values from rows

Comment: `array_agg(distinct ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `array_agg(distinct ...)` works for scalar values, but my columns have type `int[]`

Comment: Obviously you need to unnest those values before you can aggregate them with distinct. To be honest: if you need something like that you should probably think about normalizing your model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
with cte as (select 
        unnest( a_list::text[] )::integer as a_list, 
        unnest( b_list::text[] )::integer as b_list, 
        unnest( c_list::text[] )::integer as c_list, 
        unnest( d_list::text[] )::integer as d_list,
        (select count(type) from t) as type
    from t 
    where type = 30
)
select array_agg(distinct a_list),array_agg(distinct b_list)
,array_agg(distinct c_list),array_agg(distinct d_list),type from cte group by type ;
```

Result:

```
"{1,2,3,4,5}";"{2,4,NULL}";"{1,4,NULL}";"{2,4,5}";3
```

Comment: I get syntax error `ERROR:  column "a_list" does not exist
LINE 2:         unnest( a_list::text[] )::integer as a_list, `

Comment: Thank you, works great. One more question, why I need this cast   `::text[] )::integer`?

Comment: Actually I thought the data type is string. There is not need as already you are using integer array Datatype..You can try with unnest( a_list::integer[] )as a_list It works fine..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this take on old answer from this post:
[All Permutations of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522791/all-permutations-of-an-array)

this lists unique ordered permutations of an INT array grouped by something (*row_id* and *instrument_id* in my case) on quite decent time for arrays with length <= 10 :

You may need to install the **intarray** extension ...

```
WITH RECURSIVE data AS (
                           SELECT a1.instrument_id, ARRAY_AGG(a1.obs_pos ORDER BY a1.obs_pos) AS arr
                           FROM tmp_xxxx a1
                           GROUP BY 1
                       )
   , keys           AS (
                           SELECT instrument_id, GENERATE_SUBSCRIPTS(d.arr, 1) AS rn
                           FROM data d
                       )
   , cte            AS (
                           SELECT DISTINCT x.instrument_id
                                         , public.sort(x.initial_arr) AS initial_arr
                                         , public.sort(x.new_arr)     AS new_arr
                                         , public.sort(x.used_rn)     AS used_rn
                           FROM (
                                    SELECT d.instrument_id
                                         , d.arr               initial_arr
                                         , ARRAY [d.arr[k.rn]] new_arr
                                         , ARRAY [k.rn]        used_rn
                                    FROM data d
                                    JOIN keys k
                                         ON d.instrument_id = k.instrument_id
                                ) x
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT DISTINCT c.instrument_id
                                         , public.sort(initial_arr)                      AS initial_arr
                                         , public.sort(c.new_arr || c.initial_arr[k.rn]) AS new_arr
                                         , public.sort(used_rn || k.rn)                  AS used_rn
                           FROM cte  c
                           JOIN keys k
                                ON c.instrument_id = k.instrument_id AND NOT (k.rn = ANY (c.used_rn))
                       )
INSERT
INTO tmp_xxxx( row_id
                      , instrument_id
                      , obs_pos_array
                      )
SELECT DISTINCT _row_id              AS row_id
              , cte.instrument_id
              , public.sort(new_arr) AS obs_pos_array
FROM cte
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(new_arr, 1) >= 2 -- change it to your needs
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_xxxx DO NOTHING;
```